# sudo update-grub problem

Tags: 13.04, grub2

To say I am new to Linux would be an understatement (I've had Ubuntu 13.04 installed for about 5 hours), so bear with me.

I was having some issues with not being able to change the back light on my laptop, and after several attempted fixes still haven't gotten anywhere, but right now my issue is this: when I try to use the `sudo update-grub` command, I get this in return:

`/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/defaut.grub: logout: not found`

I assume I unwittingly changed something of importance, as it was updating fine a short time ago, but I am not sure how to fix it?

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` and [edit] the full output into your question (via copy/paste). Can you also add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal, and add the Boot Repair PPA

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Install Boot Repair

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Update the GRUB 2 configuration file

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Reinstall GRUB 2 to the drive's MBR or equivalent

Install to the drive, not to the partition. Example: sda, not sda1

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Inspect the GRUB 2 configuration file. The default is /boot/grub/grub.cfg

for more information visit how to update [GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading)

Comment: Boot Repair is **not always** required. In this case, the problem is evident and can be fixed without it.